# Problem with activeModal.close Angular TS

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Please help to solve problem with closing modal window. I wrote function but button do nothing
Button Close:

```
 <button type="submit"
                (click)="activeModal.close()"
                class="btn btn-outline-danger">Закрыть
        </button>
```

Method in tS file:

```
 closeModal() {
this.activeModal.close();
```

}

Full HTML:

```
 <button class="btn btn-outline-warning" (click)="openModal(NewRow)">Добавить запись в журнал</button>

<ng-template #NewRow>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Новая запись</h4>
    <!--   <button (click)="closeModal()" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"  >-->
    <!-- <button type="button" class="close"  data-dismiss="modal">
       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
     </button>-->
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form role="form" #logbook="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="logbook.form.valid && onSubmit()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Дата</label>
        <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="newRow.date" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" name="date" required="required"
               class="form-control" id="date">

        <label>Дисциплина</label>
        <select name="subject1" required="required" [(ngModel)]="newRow.subjectId" class="form-control"
                [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }">

          <option name="subject" required="required" [value]="subject.id"
                  *ngFor="let subject of subjects">{{subject.subject}}</option>
        </select>
        <label>Тип занятия</label>
        <select name="type1" required [(ngModel)]="newRow.typeId" class="form-control"
                [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone: true }">

          <option name="type" required="required" [value]="typeOfClass.id"
                  *ngFor="let typeOfClass of typeOfClasses">{{typeOfClass.name}}</option>
        </select>

        <label>Количество часов</label>
        <input required="required" type="number" name="hours" [(ngModel)]="newRow.hours" class="form-control"
               id="hours">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit"
                (click)="activeModal.close()"
                class="btn btn-outline-danger">Закрыть
        </button>
        <button (click)="saveNewRow()" [disabled]="logbook.form.invalid" class="btn btn-outline-success">Добавить
        </button>

      </div>

    </form>
  </div>


</ng-template>
```

Full  TS file:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {AuthService} from "../../services/auth.service";
import {TokenStorageService} from "../../services/token-storage.service";
import {NgbActiveModal, NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {SubjectService} from "../../services/subject.service";
import {TypeOfClassService} from "../../services/typeOfClass.service";
import {Subject} from "../../common/subject";
import {TypeOfClass} from "../../common/typeOfClass";
import {Subscription} from "rxjs";
import {Logbook} from "../../common/logbook";
import {LogbookService} from "../../services/logbook.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-row',
  templateUrl: './add_new_row.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add_new_row.component.css']
})
export class AddNewRowComponent implements OnInit {

  form: any = {};
  isLoggedIn = false;
  isLoginFailed = false;
  errorMessage = '';
  roles: string[] = [];
  subjects: Subject[];
  typeOfClasses: TypeOfClass[];
  public newRow: Logbook = new Logbook();
  closeResult = '';
  private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
              private tokenStorage: TokenStorageService,
              private modalService: NgbModal,
              private activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
              private subjectService: SubjectService,
              private logbookService: LogbookService,
              private typeOfClassService: TypeOfClassService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadAllTypes(), this.loadAllSubjects();
    if (this.tokenStorage.getToken()) {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      this.roles = this.tokenStorage.getUser().roles;
    }

  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.authService.login(this.form).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.tokenStorage.saveToken(data.accessToken);
        this.tokenStorage.saveUser(data);

        this.isLoginFailed = false;
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        this.roles = this.tokenStorage.getUser().roles;
        this.reloadPage();
      },
      err => {
        this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
        this.isLoginFailed = true;
      }
    );
  }


  openModal(template) {
    this.modalService.open(template);

  }

 
  closeModal() {
    this.activeModal.close();
  }

  saveNewRow() {
    this.subscriptions.push(this.logbookService.add(this.newRow).subscribe(() => {
      this.newRow = new Logbook();
      this.reloadPage();
    }))
  }

  private loadAllTypes(): void {
    this.subscriptions.push(this.typeOfClassService.getAllTypes().subscribe(type => {
      this.typeOfClasses = type as TypeOfClass[];
    }))
  }

  private loadAllSubjects() {
    this.subscriptions.push(this.subjectService.getAllSubjects().subscribe(subject => {
      this.subjects = subject as Subject[];
    }))
  }

  reloadPage() {
    window.location.reload();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the solution. Use modalService and dont forget to put reason.
(click)="modalService.dismissAll('Cross click')"

Answer (score 0):

A modal service usually returns a `ModalReference` in your case that is `this.activeModal` you tried to use the ModalReference but it is not assigned anywhere?

My guess:

change this:

```
openModal(template) {
    this.modalService.open(template);

  }
```

to this:

```
openModal(template) {
    this.activeModal = this.modalService.open(template);

  }
```

Comment: But with open I have no problems, problem is with close button

Comment: Have you tried it? You are using the ngb-bootstrap version of modal, from: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples I am not that familiar with this specific version, but generally the modal service passes a reference back that you can use to identify the relevant modal to be closed. This is also shown on the examples page? See: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#component and open the code-view on `modal-component-ts` ?

Comment: See also on the API page: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api#NgbModalRef

Comment: Yes, I tried almost all of it. I don't know whats wrong. It is just doesnt react on my click.

Comment: Maybe you know methods to find why it is not react?

Comment: As indicated, follow the guidelines on the ngb website... The method you are using `activeModal` would imply that modal body gets injected into the `modalService.open()` as a component, (the content component) but I do not get the impression that that is what you are doing? You seem to have content as a template => which is not the same as having it as it;s own component?